# How to format for aligning select in Toad for Oracle

Tags: toad

I'm using Toad for Oracle 10.6 and when I write a SQL statement like this:

```
select *
from table1,
    table2,
    table3
where col1 = 3
and col2 = 5
and col3 = 6;
```

I use a TAB button after every AND and I'd like to get something like;

```
select *
from table1,
     table2,
     table3
where col1 = 3
and   col2 = 5
and   col3 = 6;
```

but in View/Formatting Options I can't find where to tune
Could you help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why would you *ever* manually format code? Use built-in formatter; adjust its setting so that they fit your needs.

For what you described, it looks like the following:

[image]

Formatter shortcut is `<Ctrl + Shift + F>`.

Comment: Thanks but after doing what you told me and saving, if I click on <Ctrl + Shift + F> I get this:

select *
  from table1, table2, table3
 where col1 = 3 and col2 = 5 and col3 = 6;

Comment: Well, review **all** formatter settings, see what they do and what result they produce, until you find combination you're satisfied with.

Comment: Hi,
thank you very much for the answer.
What I'd also like to have is the opportunity to have the right aligning automatically without having to select all the query and push to "Formatting Tools --> Format". For example with PLSQL Developer (Allround Automation) I get immediatly the desidered/personalyzed format as soon as I give <tab> on my keyboards after every row of the query.
Mark